# MediaWiki - Get namespaces by user

Tags: xml, url, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Is it possible to get an XML list of every namespace a given user group can edit in MediaWiki?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking here. Do you want a list of user groups? Or a list of MediaWiki namespaces? (These are two different things, in no way whatsoever related.) Or are you (just guessing here) interested in wgNamespaceProtection settings?

Comment: Could be a good question if edited to be better understandable. I didn't dare to edit since it's not clear what is asked for.

Comment: I know the difference between namespaces and user goups. And I use both in my MediaWiki. The user group decides in which namespace a user has access. Now I want a list in which you can see every namespace in which a user group has access (user group: "user" has access in namespaces: "user1", "user2")

Comment: Took a guess at what OP actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature (yet), because in MediaWiki by default everyone can read and edit everything except the MediaWiki namespace: see [$wgNamespaceProtection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespaceProtection).

You can get the list of namespaces [api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces|usergroups&format=xml](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces|usergroups&format=xml) and then [Special:ListGroupRights](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:ListGroupRights) tells you about further namespace protections, then you can check what groups have rights on what namespaces.